# Reverse DNS Lookup Zones

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, reverse-dns

I have two domain controllers that act as a Primary and Secondary DNS servers. Server2 is the primary and server1 is the secondary. If I open dnsmgnt on server2 and look at the Reverse Lookup Zones, it looks like this:
[image: Test 1]

If I look at the Reverse Lookup Zones on server1, it looks like this:
[image: Test2]

What is causing this to be different? On a side note, does every domain controller with a global catalog need to have itself as a DNS server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's Advanced mode for that MMC snapin, in the View menu - shows the actual zone name instead of the "easier" version.

Not sure exactly what you mean by "have itself as a DNS server" - can you expand on that (and maybe make it a separate question)?

Comment: Thank you. I will open another question for the second question.

Comment: I think he is asking if every domain controller must be a DNS server.  The answer to that is no.

Comment: no, I was asking if every Domain Controller that has the global catalog enabled should also have DNS Server installed.